# Local Identity based login along with saml 2.0 SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, saml, openid-connect

There is an existing mechanism to log into a website. Now, external / remote SAML IDP is being added to facilitate SSO. The website uses other micro-services and components that provide data and functionality to the website.

Is there a way to have an existing mechanism of local identity username password credentials to continue to co-exist as an alternate strategy for authentication alongside remote IDP SSO while keeping rest of the services handling authorization in a semantic way (using a saml token)?

P.S. I looked at the options to implement existing auth mechanism as saml IDP, but building it seems complex even with the likes of shibboleth or openSAML libraries.

P.P.S. I haven't looked at possibility of reimplementing existing auth mechanism with openId connect to co-exist with remote saml idps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: one can provide a landing page to the user that gives a choice between using a local account or an account at a remote IDP.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but would such local account authentication follow oauth 2.0, openid connect or saml semantics to generate a bearer token for compatibility with remote idp?